# Resize opening modal in angularJs

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-dialog

I'm creating modal with angularjs. When I opened the page,
It is supposed to automatically adjust its size at different resolutions. 
I do CSS settings auto, but it has not changed.
I want to do with Different resolutions of the same coating

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('testPadding', ['ngDialog']);

    app.config(['ngDialogProvider', function (ngDialogProvider) {
        ngDialogProvider.setDefaults({
            className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
        });
    }]);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, ngDialog, $timeout) {

        $scope.open = function () {
            ngDialog.open({ template: 'firstDialogId' });
        };
    });
</script>
```

***screenshots:***

[**1920x1080**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLagi.png)

[**800x600**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evjVz.png)

Comment: without knowing more about the code, you can add/modify a css class for that modal, and set the width to 100%

Comment: Please show your code and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)